# Get total number of occurrences of a data item from nested array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with a structure like:

```
$arr = [
  'data1' => [ /* some data */],
  'data2' => [
    'sub-data1' => [
      [
        'id' => 1
        'status' => 'active'
      ],
      [
        'id' => 2
        'status' => 'not-active'
      ]
    ],
    'sub-data2' => [
      [
        'id' => 3
        'status' => 'active'
      ],
      [
        'id' => 4
        'status' => 'active'
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Is there a simple way in which I can count how many `sub-dataxxx` have **any** item with a `status` is `active`?

I have managed to do this with nested foreach loops, but I'm wondering if there is a more simple method?

The above example should show the number of active entries as 2, as there are 2 `sub-data` elements with `active` statuses. This ignores any non-active statuses.

**Edit: To clarify my expected result**

I am not wanting to count the number of `status = active` occurrences. I'm wanting to count the number of `sub-dataxxx` elements that contain an element with `status = active`.

So in this instance, both of `sub-data1` and `sub-data2` contain sub-elements that contain `status = active`, therefore my count should be 2.

Comment: same as @NigelRen i think it should be **3** not **2**.

Comment: @NigelRen I've added a clarifier to the end of my question to hopefully clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it quite easily with a function like this

```
function countActiveSubData(array $data): int
{
    return array_reduce($data, function ($res, $sub) {
        foreach ($sub as $d) {
            if ('active' === $d['status']) {
                return $res + 1;
            }
        }

        return $res;
    }, 0);
}
```

you can call it on a single data or if you want to get the result for entire $arr you can call it like this

```
$result = array_map('countActiveSubData', $arr);

// the result will be [
  'data1' => 0,
  'data2'=> 2
   ....
  ]
```